# Android - Notifications PendingIntent goes to wrong Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

I currently have a notification that displays in the notification bar and when the user clicks it it should bring them to the root Activity of my application.

I have used android:finishOnTaskLaunch ="true" & android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in my manifest to achieve this when the user presses the app icon from the apps screen or the home screen. The user is always taken to the root activity as expected.

However when I use the following code from my notification the user gets taken to the last screen they were on rather than the root activity which is StartActivity.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
   contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
   notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.notification_app_name), notificationText, contentIntent);
   mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Adding these flags helps however it still doesn't work after a restart:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

When I restart my application I set a service running which pops up the notification and when I do this the notification reverts back to the old undesired behavior .

SOLVED:

Solved the issue by adding this flag to the contentIntent of my notification - Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED.

Here is an link with some excellent information on the area **[Google dev group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/da024bcaf4e1960f)**

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you used: FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this 2 properties

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Interestingly it works when I first run the app, however I have an autostart feature that pops the notification in up when the phone is rebooted and when this is enabled and actived (EG: I restart and pop up the notification) the notification reverts back to the old behavior despite running the exact same code when it auto starts.

Comment: Dint got when you restart the phone your application show notification and by clicking it should got to the root actvity rather than its going on some other activity like tht is happening ?

Comment: Yes I solved the issue by adding this to the contentIntent of my notification - Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED